# docker-compose launch cmd to set env variable

Tags: docker-compose

I created an container able to set the uid of my user from the host with the user running Apache on the container. Like that I am able to share my directory without having any permission problem.
I am using a environment variable "CONTAINER_USER_UID" to bind those user. So I set this variable with the result of `id -u`.

I tried to add `id -u` as value into the docker-compose file but it isn't working...

```
version: '3'

services:
  members:
    image: olive007/ubuntu-php-apache:18.04-7.2-2.4
    environment:
      CONTAINER_USER_UID: `id -u`
      CONTAINER_USER_GID: `id -g`
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
```

I got this error :

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
>   found character '`' that cannot start any token

Anyone know how to set an environment variable with the result of a command ran on the host ?

Sorry for my English, I am learning it...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run bash commands from a yml file. Use [docker-compose environment variable substition](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:
  members:
    image: olive007/ubuntu-php-apache:18.04-7.2-2.4
    environment:
      CONTAINER_USER_UID: ${HOST_UID}
      CONTAINER_USER_GID: ${HOST_GID}
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
```

And then run your service as:

```
export HOST_UID=`id -u`
export HOST_GID=`id -g`
docker-compose up
```